# xsl for-each loop not working correctly(logic)

Tags: xslt, foreach, iteration, transform

I have applied one logic in xsl for-each loop, but it is not behaving correctly. Can anyone help me out.

XML

```
<a>
 <b>
   <c>
     <string>16</string>
     <string>4</string>
     <string>id</string>
     <int>123</int>
   </c>
   <c>
     <string>16</string>
     <string>4</string>
     <string>id</string>
     <int>123</int>
  </c>
</b>
</a>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:for-each select="/a/b/c">
   <c>      
    <xsl:for-each select="/a/b/c/string">"
        <xsl:variable name ="pos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() mod 2!=0">
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="self::node()[text()='16']">
                   <int>16</int><int>4</int>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:element name="{/a/b/c/string[position()=$pos]}">"
                         <xsl:value-of select="/a/b/c/string[position()=$pos+1]\/>
                    </xsl:element>
               </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</c>        </xsl:for-each>
```

Desired Output

```
  <a>
     <b>
       <c>
         <int>16</int>
         <int>4</int>
         <id>123</id>
      </c>
     <c>
        <int>16</int>
        <int>4</int>
        <id>123</id>
    </c>
  </b>
</a>
```

Actual Output

```
<a>
<b>
<c>
<int>16</int>
<int>4</int>
<id>123</id>
<int>16</int>
<int>4</int>
</c>
<c>
<int>16</int>
<int>4</int>
<id>123</id>
<int>16</int>
<int>4</int>
</c>
</b>
</a>
```

There is some problem in inner for-each loop but I am not able to find out

Comment: The way you phrase your question suggests a problem of mindset. If a program doesn't do what you expect, then there's a 99.9% chance that your expectations are wrong. Start by saying "I have made a mistake", rather than "the program is behaving incorrectly", and you immediately position yourself in the right place to start searching for the reason.

Comment: sorry @MichaelKay but I wrote xsl for-each loop not working correctly(logic). Everywhere I mentioned that I have applied a logice but that logic is not working according to me, I clearly said its my mistake only not prog's ... :) anyways, I will keep your suggestion in mind.

Comment: Perhaps it's just use of English. The program is working correctly according to the language specification. That doesn't mean it is doing what you would like it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your inner for-each loop

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/a/b/c/string">
```

When an xpath expression starts with "/" , it means it is an absolute expression. The "/" refers to the top-level document node, and it will start selecting things starting right back at the root of the XML, regardless of where you are currently positioned in the XML.

What you want is a relative expression. At the point you do your inner "for-each" your current context is the "c" element, so all you need to write is this

```
<xsl:for-each select="string">
```

This will return only "string" elements that are children of the current "c" element.

Also, your current xsl:element statement can then change. Instead of doing this

```
<xsl:element name="{/a/b/c/string[position()=$pos]}">
```

You can simply do this

```
<xsl:element name="{.}">
```

And to get the value of the following element at this point, do this.

```
<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="a/b/c">
       <c>      
        <xsl:for-each select="string">
            <xsl:if test="position() mod 2!=0">
                <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="self::node()[text()='16']">
                       <int>16</int><int>4</int>
                   </xsl:when>
                   <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:element name="{.}">
                             <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                   </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </c>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```